# Command line parsing lib VLang

Tags: vlang

I want to write a command line application with the [V programming language](https://vlang.io/). Is there a library for command line parsing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [nedpals/vargs](https://github.com/nedpals/vargs) library.

Comment: It seems that this answer should not be considered as an accepted one, since https://github.com/nedpals/vargs repository is archived already 3-4 years and there are other modern solutions provided in other answers. Please change accepted answer for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 9):

As of November 2020, the command-line arguments parsing is included in the standard library.

[Example from *V* repository](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/110c7e6f90e4c65f6a25db2a3816ed2b0c322d28/examples/cli.v)

```golang
import cli { Command, Flag }
import os

fn main() {
    mut cmd := Command{
        name: 'cli'
        description: 'An example of the cli library.'
        version: '1.0.0'
    }
    mut greet_cmd := Command{
        name: 'greet'
        description: 'Prints greeting in different languages.'
        usage: '<name>'
        required_args: 1
        pre_execute: greet_pre_func
        execute: greet_func
        post_execute: greet_post_func
    }
    greet_cmd.add_flag(Flag{
        flag: .string
        required: true
        name: 'language'
        abbrev: 'l'
        description: 'Language of the message.'
    })
    greet_cmd.add_flag(Flag{
        flag: .int
        name: 'times'
        value: '3'
        description: 'Number of times the message gets printed.'
    })
    cmd.add_command(greet_cmd)
    cmd.parse(os.args)
}
```

Output

```
$ v run ./examples/cli.v 
Usage: cli [flags] [commands]

An example of the cli library.

Flags:
  -help               Prints help information.
  -version            Prints version information.

Commands:
  greet               Prints greeting in different languages.
  help                Prints help information.
  version             Prints version information.
```

Answer (score 5):

yes, the os module. this example outputs each command line argument

```
import os

fn main() {
    for arg in os.args {
        println(arg)
    }
}
```

when run on my system: `program.exe hello!` returns

```
D:\Documents\V\program.exe
hello!
```

Edit: I now see what you were aiming for with command line parsing. No, there are no existing modules that allow you to do this.

Comment: I wouldn't consider `os` a library for command line parsing. I was looking for something like e.g. Python's [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the official `flag` module.
See for example:
https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/689003454b5c60fa13a6a0b44c39f79847806609/tools/performance_compare.v#L204

This produces something like this from the user perspective:

```
0[13:29:12] /v/nv $ tools/performance_compare --help
performance_compare 0.0.4
-----------------------------------------------
Usage: performance_compare [options] COMMIT_BEFORE [COMMIT_AFTER]

Description:
  Compares V executable size and performance,
  between 2 commits from V's local git history.
  When only one commit is given, it is compared to master.

The arguments should be at least 1 and at most 2 in number.

Options:
  --help <bool>:false       Show this help screen

  --vcrepo <string>:https://github.com/vlang/vc
                            The url of the vc repository. You can clone it
                            beforehand, and then just give the local folder
                            path here. That will eliminate the network ops
                            done by this tool, which is useful, if you want
                            to script it/run it in a restrictive vps/docker.

  --verbose <bool>:false    Be more verbose

  --hyperfine_options <string>:
                            Additional options passed to hyperfine.
                            For example on linux, you may want to pass:
                               --hyperfine_options "--prepare 'sync; echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'"

  --workdir <string>:/tmp   A writable folder, where the comparison will be done.

0[13:29:13] /v/nv $
```

Answer (score 1):

Natively:

```
import os
import flag



const (
    tool_version = '0.0.4'
)


mut fp := flag.new_flag_parser(os.args)
fp.version( tool_version )
```

With v-args library:

```
import vargs // or import nedpals.vargs for vpm users
import os

fn main() {
    // Second argument removes the first argument which contains the path of the executable.
    mut _args := vargs.new(os.args, 1)
    
    // Use the `alias` method if you want to map an option to an existing option.
    _args.alias('W', 'with')

    // Parsing is now a separate step
    _args.parse()

    println(_args.str())
    println(_args.command)
    println(_args.unknown[0])
    println('with? ' + _args.options['with'])
}
```